# pinentry-mac fails to store password in Keychain

Tags: git, gpg

I'm using gpg to sign my git commits. I'm using pinentry-mac to store the password in the Keychain. This works fine on most macs. But I have one mac mini on which I get prompted again for the password every login session.

I have most certainly checked `Save in Keychain` but it does not seem to work.

I have searched in the `Keychain Access` app for `gnupg` and I can't find anything.

How can I fix this?